# How do I find DNS servers in use by my Xubuntu 14.04 Server?

Tags: server, xubuntu, dns

I have a Xubuntu Server 14.04 x64.

How do I list all DNS servers that are in use without NetworkManager which is not even installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right now )

Answer (score 5):

The DNS setting can be specified in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `resolve.conf` could be blank. Because the DNS entry can be in multiple locations, I think it is best to do an actual DNS query with the verbose mode switch. The output lines that start with the word "Received" will show the DNS server used by your host. In this example, I use www.news.com

`host -v www.news.com | grep Received`

Comment: This looked promising, but
ubuntu@ip-10-0-100-203:~$ host -v www.news.com | grep Received
Received 89 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 243 ms
Received 100 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 57 ms
Received 100 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 57 ms

Answer (score 0):

To extend answer from **@fkraiem**:

You can list DNS servers currently in use by executing the following command from the terminal:

```
more /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

DNS servers are configured during DHCP negotiation or specified statically in `/etc/network/interfaces`. After that they are added dynamically to `/etc/resolv.conf`. Do not edit this file though as it will be overwritten with each network switch or system reboot.